# Error while coping List to a new Array

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I want the SQL database table Bind in GridView.Here, I used Ajax in order to call Web Method named 'GetProducts' through 'url', using HTTP POST verb. It executes the select query and returns the data.Here is the code but there shows and error in 'p.ToArray()'.It says Cannot be implicitly converted.Please help me to make this code run able.Also suggest me if there is any error in other part of the code:
This is the code inside .aspx.cs page:

```
namespace AvailableProductsWithAjax
{
    public partial class AvailableProductsWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                this.BindDummyRow();
            }

          //  GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;


        }
        private void BindDummyRow()
        {
            DataTable dummy = new DataTable();
            //dummy.Columns.Add("Product_Id");
            dummy.Columns.Add("Product_Name");
            dummy.Columns.Add("Product_Description");
            dummy.Columns.Add("Product_Category");
            dummy.Columns.Add("Product_Price");
            dummy.Columns.Add("Product_Quantity");
            dummy.Rows.Add();
            GridView1.DataSource = dummy;
            GridView1.DataBind();


        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static Products GetProducts()
        {
            List<Products> p = new List<Products>();
            string query = "Select Product_Name, Product_Description, Product_Category, Product_Price, Product_Quantity from Items";


            String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebShopDB"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = query;

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Products ps = new Products();

                        ps.Products_Name = dtRow["Product_Name"].ToString();
                        ps.Products_Category = dtRow["Product_Category"].ToString();
                        ps.Products_Description = dtRow["Product_Description"].ToString();
                        ps.Products_Price = dtRow["Product_Price"].ToString();
                        ps.Products_Quantity = dtRow["Product_Quantity"].ToString();


                    }

                }

            }
            return p.ToArray();  
            // Here is the error, cannot be converted implicitly
        }

            public class Products

            public int Products_Id { get; set; }
            public string Products_Name { get; set; }
            public string Products_Description { get; set; }

            public string Products_Category { get; set; }
            public string Products_Price { get; set; }
            public string Products_Quantity { get; set; }
        }
    }
  }
```

Here is the JQuery Ajax function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AvailableProductsWebForm.aspx/GetProducts",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: {},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (data) {
                        alert(data.d +" Its a failure");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(data.d +" It's an error");
                    }
                });
            });
            function OnSuccess() {
                $("#GridView1").empty();
                if(data.d.length>0)
                {
                    $("#GridView1").append("<tr><th>Product_Name</th> <th>Product_Category</th> <th>Product_Description </th> <th>Product_Price</th> <th> Product_Quantity</th></tr>");
                    for(var i=0; i<data.d.length; i++)
                    {
                        $("#GridView1").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].Product_Name +"</td> <td>"
                            + data.d[i].Product_Category + "</td> <td>"
                            + data.d[i].Product_Description +
                            data.d[i].Product_Price + "</td> <td>" +
                            data.d[i].Product_Quantity + "</td> <td>" 
                          );
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Here is my database query:

```
USE [WebShop]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [Product_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Product_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Product_Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Product_Category] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Product_Price] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Product_Quantity] [varchar](50) NULL,
GO
```

Please help me to run this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is `Products`, but you are trying to return `List<Products>`.
Change your method signature to

```
public static List<Products> GetProducts()
```

Second, you are not filling your return value. Variable p remains empty.
So you should add ps into p in foreach loop

```
p.Add(ps);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return it in `Products[]` instead `Products`

So your code should be

```
[WebMethod]
    public static Products[] GetProducts()
    {
        List<Products> p = new List<Products>();
        string query = "Select Product_Name, Product_Description, Product_Category, Product_Price, Product_Quantity from Items";
```

Let me know if more assistance required....